# How to create a n-gram function from this function that I have?

Tags: python, string, n-gram

I have this following function that counts character in a string in order the string is written:

```
def count_char(s):
    result = {}
    for i in range(len(s)):
        result[s[i]] = s.count(s[i])
    return result
```

For example. we have:

```
count_char("practice")
{'p' : 1, 'r' : 1, 'a' : 1, 'c' : 2, 't' : 1, 'i' : 1, 'e' : 1}
```

From this function, how do I create a function that counts the number of times each n-gram occurs in a string? For example,

```
ngrams("tataki",n=2)
{'ta':2, 'at':1, 'ak':1, 'ki':1}
```

The function `ngrams` should be a modification to the function `count_char`, but I am not sure how to do it at this point...

Comment: What about overlapping `n-grams`? For example, what should be the output for `ngrams('ttt', 2)`?

Comment: I think the output should be ```{'tt':2}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a length parameter to your function; then just extend your slices from 1 character to that length:

```py
def count_char(s, l = 1):
    result = {}
    for i in range(len(s)-l+1):
        result[s[i:i+l]] = s.count(s[i:i+l])
    return result

print(count_char("practice"))
print(count_char('tataki', 2))
```

Output:

```py
{'p': 1, 'r': 1, 'a': 1, 'c': 2, 't': 1, 'i': 1, 'e': 1}
{'ta': 2, 'at': 1, 'ak': 1, 'ki': 1}
```

Note that [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20count#str.count) only counts non-overlapping occurrences, so `count_char('ttt', 2)` will return 1, not 2. If you want to count overlapping occurrences, you need to do that manually. For example:

```py
def count_char(s, l = 1):
    result = {}
    for i in range(len(s)-l+1):
        sub = s[i:i+l]
        if sub not in result:
            result[sub] = sum(s[j:j+l] == sub for j in range(len(s)-l+1))
    return result
```

This function will return `2` when called as `count_char('ttt', 2)`.